# Horizontally Mirror Android XML Layout

Tags: android, xml

I've got a layout that is horizontally mirrored, i.e. views that are left-aligned on the left side of the screen, and views that are right-aligned on on the right side of the screen.
It's somewhat tedious to make a change to the left views, and then have to copy changes to the right views, while switching all of the orientations from left to right.
For example, this textView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/other_view"/>
```

Would have to be duplicated on the other side with this textView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/other_view"/>
```

It's manageable, but I'm curious if there's a better solution than copy-paste-change each time. Perhaps something could be done programmatically, but doing that eliminates the benefit of seeing changes as you design in XML.